Is possible to intersect scene leave event in Telegraf.js?
I create 2 service (service with scene and service starts scene) in Nest.js and enter to scene. Can i handle leaving from scene at the point where I entered the scene?
Promise ctx.scene.enter('scene-id') is not awaiting leaving from scene
